# Outlook 365 get Mail Item

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office365api

I have following problem:
We have an Outlook Addin (VSTO), with which we archive emails (orders) in SAP. 
Now the plugin should be implemented for Outlook 365. I already looked at the new api and i get die subject or maitext but there seems no way to get to the raw .msg file.

So my question now is, is there a way to get an mailitem as an .msg file (or any other format)?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways may be you can try

Use the process to run the .msg

```
string file= @"C:\PWS\myMail.msg";
Process.Run(file);
```

Use OpenSharedItem to open it:

```
var app = new Outlook.Application();
var item = app.Session.OpenSharedItem(msgfile) as Outlook.MailItem;

//Do stuff with the mail.

item.Close(OlInspectorClose.olDiscard);
app.Quit();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item);
```